# jQuery Mobile - Multiple popups issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

I'm having an issue in my jQuery Mobile site, I have 3 separate pages (within one index.html file), all which load their own popup on a success event, I'm then loading the popup via jQuery like:

```
$( "#myPopupDiv" ).popup( "open" );
```

This works great, however once the user has visited a page and opened its popup, when visiting the subsequent pages, the popups on those pages then don't fire (however the popup on that page works for the duration of the session still), however all of the code works on the page and there are no console errors in Chrome dev tools.

I don't have any duplicate ID's, I have tried putting in a console.log where the code should fire to open the popup, this works correctly, seemingly bypassing the code to open the popup.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Thanks in advance.

**Simplified Code example**

```
<!-- PAGE 1 -->
<div data-role="page" id="page-1">
    <div data-role="content">
        <!-- BUTTON: loadPopup-1 -->
        <div id="popup-1" data-role="popup">
        <!-- Popup contents -->
        </div><!-- /popup -->
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<!-- PAGE 2 -->
<div data-role="page" id="page-2">
    <div data-role="content">
        <!-- BUTTON: loadPopup-2 -->
        <div id="popup-2" data-role="popup">
        <!-- Popup contents -->
        </div><!-- /popup -->
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<!-- JS -->
function loadPopup-1() {
    $( "#popup-1" ).popup( "open" );
}

function loadPopup-2() {
    $( "#popup-2" ).popup( "open" );
}
```

So if the user selects page 1 and opens its popup, that popup will continue to work however the one on page 2 will not, and vice-versa.

Comment: Need to see some code....

Comment: Updated with some code

Comment: When are you calling the `loadPopup-*()` functions?

Comment: I've simplified it in the case of this example but it's the line above the actual popup, I've put in comments saying `BUTTON: loadPopup-*` which then runs the JS code

Comment: So click on a button opens popup?

Comment: Yes, in the real example, the user is posting something from a form, on success the JS is ran which is the JS code shown in the example.

Comment: As far as I know that if a page is in DOM, popups & dialogs will fire once. Removing `.remove()` pages from DOM would solve the problem, Im working on a similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

It does not seem to be possible to have more than one JQM popup open at a time.

From the doco:
Note: Chaining of popups not allowed
The framework does not currently support chaining of popups so it's not possible to embed a link from one popup to another popup. All links with a data-rel="popup" inside a popup will not do anything at all.

This also means that custom select menus will not work inside popups, because they are themselves implemented using popups. If you place a select menu inside a popup, it will be rendered as a native select menu, even if you specify data-native-menu="false".

Answer (score 3):

You should show more code,so we can understand the issue...what is the trigger for popup functions?
Until then, I suggest you to do something else:

Create one function that creates a generic popup on active page, and then opens it...

Sample Code:

```
function ShowPopUp(PopupText){

   // check if popup element already exists
   if($("#PopUp").length > 0)
      $("#PopUp").remove();

   // get active (current) page ID
   var id = $.mobile.activePage.attr("id");

   // add popup element to the active page
   $("#" + id).append("<div data-role='popup' id='PopUp' class='ui-content' data-position-to='window' data-overlay-theme='a'></div>");

   // add your text to the popup
   $("#PopUp").html(PopupText);

   // "refresh" the page with new popup elements
   $("#" + id ).trigger('create');

   // open the popup
   $("#PopUp").popup("open");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/serbanghita/jQM-dynamic-popup - I'm using this in production already since 2012.

Encapsulate `$.dynamic_popup(' ... HTML code ... ');` in your functions. You can trigger as many jQuery Mobile popups as you like.